# VueJs v-if prevents real-time notifications

Tags: vue.js

When I add v-if to anchor element than the real-time notifications are not being shown, I see them after page refresh. But without that v-if everything works fine. Here is my code.

[Notification.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0kcV.png)

[NotificationItem.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsULp.png)

So after a lot of tries I still can’t figure out this problem.
I would appreciate any feedback.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Vue devtools? Does `notification.type` match `'App\\Notifications\\NewBookAdded'` exactly? Your if not evaluating to `true` would be the cause of this

Comment: notification.type returns App\Notifications\NewBookAdded. But I added double slashes in the string so that they could be considered as real slashes.

Comment: So you need to remove the extra backslashes. You're not getting an exact match.

Comment: If we want to have slashes in a string we should write it as \\. Isn't it right?

Comment: Yes, but have you tried single slashes?

Comment: yes I tried, in that case notifications are not being shown even after the page refresh

Comment: the problem is that I get notifications number +1 in case of new notification, but when I hover on the anchor I can't see the notification